# How to build using Colcon inside a Dockerfile

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, build, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use docker to build and run a ROS2 node, however in order for Colcon to build the node as an instruction in the Dockerfile, it must first have ROS2 sourced. It seems though that you cannot source a script in a dockerfile instruction, so is there a way to build a Colcon workspace as part of a dockerfile?

Essentially what I'm trying to do assuming a colcon workspace has been copied to the image is:

`RUN /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/eloquent/setup.sh" && colcon build`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373976/how-to-build-using-colcon-inside-a-dockerfile/) by [jandaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/71935/jandaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2021-03-16**:
I suggest you add the "Update" as an answer and accept it instead of updating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of using the source in bash, you can use the dot operator instead, as it's supported in dash (the default shell in ubuntu based images)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

For example:

```
RUN . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.sh && \
    colcon build
```

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/3bf1f7a93d740c54b4c7ef7fc6dd914175bf46be/Dockerfile#L64-L65

You can also change the default shell in the Dockerfile:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell

but I'd suggest keeping it simple with the dot operator as above.

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2021-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jandaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/71935/jandaa/) on 2021-03-17**:
Thanks that works as well!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of

`RUN /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/eloquent/setup.sh" && colcon build`

try moving the double quote:

`RUN /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/eloquent/setup.sh && colcon build"`

---

Originally posted by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) with karma: 275 on 2021-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jandaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/71935/jandaa/) on 2021-03-16**:
Ah you're right thank you!